# Apostrophe CMS browsing for pieces keep pre-loaded pieces if user clicks on one and goes back to browsing

Tags: javascript, caching, apostrophe-cms

My client wants the ability for users to go back to the same already loaded pieces instead of having to click the "Load More" button to get back to where they were. Is there a way for apostrophe to do this or a way to cache the page to put the use back to where they were while browsing the pieces? I have basically the same setup found [here](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/advanced-topics/advanced-pieces-topics/ajax-pieces.html#filtering-without-reloading-the-page-using-ajax-to-enhance-filters) on the documents site

Comment: Are you looking to do something like scroll up the page to previously loaded pieces? Or are you wanting to go back to a previous page of results (e.g., using the numbered pager) and have that page load very quickly?

Comment: they were looking for the ability to scroll up the page to previously loaded pieces, however I did convince them to use pager instead of using the ajax and a "Load More" button which solves the issue. But I am curious if anyone has a solution to my first query.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like it would involve much Apostrophe-specific work. It might be some combination of invisible anchors and adding a button with JS to scroll the browser back up to the anchors.